# how to add devices and Apache ripple to visual studio 2015

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2015, emulation, ripple

I cant see emulators and I also cant see Apache ripple in the debugging bar, all I see is start. even when I click start it shows error.

Comment: What project type are you using? C++? Xamarin? Cordova? The debug dropdown will show different options depending on the project type.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:
[**Known Issues - Visual Studio 2015**](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/articles/known-issues/known-issues-vs2015.md)

In some cases, when you uninstall VS2013 or a previous version (RC) of VS2015, a library gets corrupted that causes the debug dropdown not to show all the target options. To resolve this issue:

1. Close all Visual Studio instances.
2. Browse "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools" folder
3. Rename the CoreCon folder to something else.
4. Launch Visual Studio again.